# Postgres show altered role config paramenters

Tags: postgresql

How do I view the configuration parameters set for a role by the command

```
ALTER ROLE myuser SET <configuration_parameter>
```

Answer (score 0):

Use `psql` and run `\drds myuser`.

Answer (score 0):

`pg_db_role_setting` records the values have been set for role and database.

```sql
SELECT 
  datname, 
  rolname, 
  setconfig 
FROM 
  pg_db_role_setting 
  LEFT JOIN pg_database ON setdatabase = pg_database.oid 
  LEFT JOIN pg_authid ON setrole = pg_authid.oid;
```

ref: https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/catalog-pg-db-role-setting.html